# Passing separate arguments or whole object to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have function that renders some templates and I want to have `user_id` and `channel_id` to be in a context each time I call it.

Is it a good practice to pass whole `action` object to a function or I should pass individual argument to context like `render_add_screen({'user_id': action.user.id, 'channel_id': action.channel.id})`? Is it worth bounding `render_add_screen` function to `action` object?

```
@action_callback('help_monitor_controls')
def do_monitor_controls_action(action):
    if action.action_value == 'add':
        return render_add_screen(action)


def render_add_screen(action=None, context=None):
    if not context:
        context = {}

    if action:
        context['user_id'] = action.user.id
        context['channel_id'] = action.channel.id

    return combine(
        render_text('screens/add/text.html', context),
        render_attachments('screens/add/select_item.json', context)
    )
```

Comment: Ya your method is better I think. Bcz action is just an instance right not the whole data. Again it depends on your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are always going to be using parameters from a single object then simply passing in the object itself makes it much clearer that you don't intend to mix and match them.

Looking at what you're showing so far however, what might make even more sense is to make an `add_to_context` method on your action object.  This might be somewhat counter-intuitive to some, as an `add` method is usually found on the collection holding the object rather than the object being added, but since the action is already deciding if it's being added to a context or not (through the `action_value` parameter) then at least you're keeping that responsibility in one place.